# Null Pointer Exception in Constructor Injection Dagger2 Android

Tags: android, dagger

I am trying to inject context in my Interactor class which is giving me a null pointer exception.
I have used the MVP pattern and I am trying to get access to the context in my non-activity class.
I am not really sure if this is the best technique used.

Module:

```
@Module
public class ContextModule {

private final Context context;

public ContextModule(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Singleton
@Provides
public Context getContext() {
    return this.context;
}
```

}

Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ContextModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

App

```
public class App extends Application {

private AppComponent appComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
            .build();
}

public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
    return appComponent;
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
TaskContract.IMainView {

@Inject
MainInteractor mainInteractor;

private MainPresnter mainPresnter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((App) getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);

    mainPresnter = new MainPresnter(this);
}

@Override
public void getRandomNumber(int rNum) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + rNum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mainPresnter.fetchFromService();
}
}
```

Presenter

```
public class MainPresnter implements TaskContract.IMainPresenter, 
TaskContract.OnTaskCompletionResult {

private TaskContract.IMainView mainView;
private MainInteractor mainInteractor;

public MainPresnter(TaskContract.IMainView mainView) {
    this.mainView = mainView;
    mainInteractor = new MainInteractor(this);
}

@Override
public void fetchFromService() {
    mainInteractor.callService();
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(int rNum) {
    mainView.getRandomNumber(rNum);
}
}
```

Interactor

```
public class MainInteractor implements TaskContract.IMainInteractor {

private static final int JOB_ID = 100 ;
private Context context;

@Inject
public MainInteractor(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


public MainInteractor(TaskContract.OnTaskCompletionResult completionListener) 
{
    TaskService.setCompletionListener(completionListener);
}

@Override
public void callService() {
    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID,
            new ComponentName(context, TaskService.class))
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setPeriodic(10000)
            .build();

    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
}
}
```

Gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
```

Comment: That's weird, everything seems actually ok, did you add the annotation processor dependency correctly?

I don't think this is the issue but maybe you can try it out with a custom scope 

`@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface MyApplicationScope {
}`

Comment: I have edited the above code, with the gradle code and custom scope is not helping, I get the same null pointer exception.

Comment: I am out of options, maybe you could try `((App) getApplicationContext()).getAppComponent().inject(this);`

instead of `getApplication`. I feel like there is something wrong related to the `applicationContext` and `Application` object.



Check out [Dagger Tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/dagger-2-the-simplest-approach-3e23502c4cab)

Answer (score 0):

You don't inject the Interactor within your Presenter - therefore it won't have a context.

You could probably restructure your Presenter to require the Interactor as a dependency - this would also mean you'd need to restructure how the completion listener is set.